# Como calcular o valor total em um table criado dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código que cria uma tabela no jquery. O problema é que eu queria criar um subtotal que somasse todos os valores da coluna total. Mas não estou conseguindo pois a tabela é criada dinamicamente. Alguma sugestão?

Segue o código:

```
function retorna_pedidos(valor)
{
 let mensagem_pedidos = "Nenhum pedido encontrado";
 let container_mostra_pedidos = $('.mostra_pedidos');
 let quantidade = $('#qtd').val();
 let quantidade_pedidos = "";
 let valorTotal = "";
 let itemHTMLp = "";

 if (valor == null)
 {
   valor = 1;
  }

 $.ajax({
  url: url_base + "pedidos?qtd=" + quantidade + "&page=" + valor,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data)
  {
  var retorno = data.pedidos.data;
  if (retorno == 0)
  {
    $('.classe-pedidos').css('display','none');
    $('.pedido-error-registro').css('display','block');
    $('.pedido-error-registro .mensagem-erro').html(mensagem_pedidos);
  }
  else
  {

    $.each(data, function(key,item) {

      let registros  = item.data.length;
      let current_page = item.current_page;
      let last_page = item.last_page;
      let next_page_url = item.next_page_url;
      let prev_page_url = item.prev_page_url;
      let pedidos = item.data;

      sessionStorage.setItem('pagina',current_page);
      sessionStorage.setItem('last_page',last_page);

      if (next_page_url == null)
      {
        if (current_page == 1)
        {
          $('.action-bar-pedido').html("<a id='btn-pagina-anterior-pedido' title='Pàgina Anterior' class='buttonPrevious btn btn-primary' style='display: none;'><< Página Anterior</a>");
        }
        else
        {
          $('.action-bar-pedido').html("<a id='btn-pagina-anterior-pedido' title='Pàgina Anterior' class='buttonPrevious btn btn-primary' style='display: block;'><< Página Anterior</a>");
        }
      }
      else if (prev_page_url == null)
      {
        $('.action-bar-pedido').html("<a id='btn-proxima-pagina-pedido' title='Próxima Página' display='block' class='buttonNext btn btn-success'>Próxima Página >></a>");
      }
      else if (prev_page_url != null || next_page_url != null)
      {
        $('.action-bar-pedido').html("<a id='btn-proxima-pagina-pedido' title='Próxima Página' display='block' class='buttonNext btn btn-success'>Próxima Página >></a><a id='btn-pagina-anterior-pedido' title='Pàgina Anterior' class='buttonPrevious btn btn-primary' style='display: block;'><< Página Anterior</a>");
      }

      for (var i in pedidos) {
        id_pedido = pedidos[i].pedidos_id;
        nome_cliente = pedidos[i].nome_cliente;
        nome_produto = pedidos[i].nome_produto;
        data_atual = pedidos[i].data;
        data_pedido = data_atual.split("-").reverse().join("/");
        frete_atual = pedidos[i].frete;
        preco_produto = pedidos[i].preco_produto;
        quantidade_pedidos = pedidos.length;
      //  console.log(pedidos);

        valorTotal =  parseFloat(quantidade_pedidos) * parseFloat(preco_produto) + frete_atual;

        itemHTMLp += "<tr>";
        itemHTMLp += "<td><input type='checkbox' value='" +  id_pedido + "' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/></td>";
        itemHTMLp += "<td>" + nome_cliente + "</td>";
        itemHTMLp += "<td>" + nome_produto + "</td>";
        itemHTMLp += "<td>" + data_pedido + "</td>";
        itemHTMLp += "<td class='frete-produto'>" + frete_atual + "</td>";
        itemHTMLp += "<td class='preco-produto'>" + preco_produto + "</td>";
        itemHTMLp += "<td class='valor-total'>" + valorTotal + "</td>";
        itemHTMLp += "</tr>";
      }
    });
    container_mostra_pedidos.html(itemHTMLp);
  }

},
error: function (data)
{
  console.log(data);
}
});
```

Comment: Sua dúvida está em como gerar o total ou no momento em qual deve fazer isso?
Se você fizer uma função que calcule o total e chamar ela depois de jogar a tabela no DOM efetivamente, você terá o que deseja. Seria esse seu problema ou seria na função de soma mesmo?

Comment: na verdade seria somar os valores do td valor-total. Que nem produto 1 = 25, produto 2 = 50, total = 75

Comment: @DiegoSantos. Seria somente somar os valores da coluna valor-total, pois ele já faz a soma do produto na variavel valorTotal

Comment: Brother, seu código tem algum erro de chave. Pode postar ele novamente corrigido? Aí eu te ajudo blz...

Comment: Eu tentei rodar ele mas ele já deu problema na interpretação...

Comment: Ok @DiegoSantos. Já arrumei

Answer (score 0):

Não está igual ao seu, pois como não tenho seus dados não tenho como simular. Mas segue...

```js
$(function(){
var total = 0;
$('.valor-total').each(function () {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
});

console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='valor-total'>1<td>
    <td class='valor-total'>15<td>
    <td>abc<td>
    <td class='valor-total'>22<td>
    <td >def<td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Deu certo. Só que tem um problema na paginação. Ele pega os totais de cada página. Daí como que eu posso somar todos eles?

Comment: hummm ai complica um pouco mais. Mas tem certeza que precisa fazer isso? Se o usuário fizer as contas do seu total ele irá achar que tem erro na página pq não bate com as informações exibidas, não? Mas se caso for necessário mesmo, seria mais interessante você voltar essa informação do servidor ou ter acesso ao total já calculado. Pq vc provavelmente pagina sua consulta, correto?

Comment: Mas pior que não tem como fazer assim...kkkkk. Será que não dava para calcular este total antes de ou seja retornar o valor de cada produto do loop e já calculá-lo?

Comment: Aí tem muitas variáveis a considerar... Por exemplo, como que é o retorno que obtém do servidor. Que informações vem nela, entende? Se você retornar todos os resultados possíveis e imagináveis neste retorno é possível somar, porém, não indico de forma alguma, por conta de performance e pq vc não conhece a máquina cliente que está acessando entende? A forma mais simples de resolver é com outra requisição ou se for retorno em json por exemplo, cria um atributo nele já com o valor somado e só pega ele no json. Que tal desta forma?

Comment: Você não quer que o valores venham de todas as páginas da paginação certo ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode calcular todos os valores das `td` percorrendo cada uma com `.each()` e somando os valores. Chamando a função abaixo você consegue o resultado total:

```js
function total(){
   tt_final = 0;
   subs = $('.valor-total');
   
   subs.each(function(){
      tt_final += parseFloat($(this).text());
   });
   
   alert(tt_final);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td class="valor-total">
         10
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="valor-total">
         4
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="valor-total">
         50
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="total()" />
```

> **Observações:**

**1.** Otimize seu código concatenando o código da tabela desta forma:

```
itemHTMLp += "<tr>"
+"<td><input type='checkbox' value='1' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/></td>"
+"<td>fulano</td>"
+"<td>produto</td>"
+"<td>14/11/2017</td>"
+"<td class='frete-produto'>0</td>"
+"<td class='preco-produto'>5</td>"
+"<td class='valor-total'>31</td>"
+"</tr>";
```

**2.** Faltou abrir e fechar a tabela com `<table>` e `</table>`:

Pode fazer assim: `container_mostra_pedidos.html('<table>'+itemHTMLp+'</table>');`

Comment: obrigado, mas o container_mostra_pedidos já é uma variável com table.